# Why does Peters feel the helicopter is small?

Tags: plot-explanation, army-of-the-dead

Scott sends Peters to the rooftop, where she finds an abandoned helicopter and prepares it:

> Peters: What the hell is this? Spend all his money on that f_cking  **miniature**?

[image: Peters walking to the helicopter]

Why does Peters feel the helicopter is small?

Comment: Peters said that in reference to the miniature used by Bly Tanaka to explain the plan. The miniature helicopter is pretty detailed and probably cost a lot of money to make, and it doesn't even describe the real helicopter. Peters expected a better helicopter based on that miniature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You misunderstand.

The sentence does not relate to the size of the helicopter, she means that it looks like no money has been spent on it.

It implies that the money spent on creating the **miniature** of the hotel complex would have been better spent on a better helicopter.

[image]

[image]